# Norm of pointwise product of Lp functions

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Does the following inequality hold in $L_p$ spaces?

$\|fg\|_p\leq\|f\|_p\|g\|_p$

How would I go about proving this? Do I need to apply Cauchy Schwarz?

Comment: Apparently the solution [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205124/fg-l2-omega-leq-f-l2-omega-g-l-infty-omega) contains a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is not true, according to [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205124/fg-l2-omega-leq-f-l2-omega-g-l-infty-omega):

If $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $f(x) = g(x) = x^{-1/3}$, we have $\|fg\|_2 = \infty$ but $\|f\|_2 = \|g\|_2 < \infty$.